# Turn object into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'm trying to turn this object into an array of objects, with the object key being placed into a property of each of the objects in the array.

Here is the input:

```
var input = {
  "2017-03-13": ["Event 1", "Event 2"],
  "2017-03-14": ["Event 1", "Event 2"],
  "2017-03-15": ["Event 1", "Event 2"]
}
```

And here is my desired output:

```
[
  {
    date: "2017-03-13",
    events: ["Event 1", "Event 2"]
  },
  {
    date: "2017-03-14",
    events: ["Event 1", "Event 2"]
  },
  {
    date: "2017-03-15",
    events: ["Event 1", "Event 2"]
  }
]
```

Any thoughts on how I might approach this? I have underscore.js at my disposal as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `Object.keys()` and `map()`.

```js
var input = {
  "2017-03-13": ["Event 1", "Event 2"],
  "2017-03-14": ["Event 1", "Event 2"],
  "2017-03-15": ["Event 1", "Event 2"]
}

var result = Object.keys(input).map(function(e) {
  return {date: e, events: input[e]}
})

console.log(result)
```

With ES6 you can do this in one line using arrow functions.

```
var result = Object.keys(input).map(e => ({date: e, events: input[e]}))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Object.keys(input).map(key => {
    date: key,
    events: input[key]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```js
var input = {
  "2017-03-13": ["Event 1", "Event 2"],
  "2017-03-14": ["Event 1", "Event 2"],
  "2017-03-15": ["Event 1", "Event 2"]
}

var output = [];
for(var key in input){
    output.push({
      date: key,
      events: input[key]
    })
}

console.log(output);
```

Or in a more functional way:

```js
var input = {
  "2017-03-13": ["Event 1", "Event 2"],
  "2017-03-14": ["Event 1", "Event 2"],
  "2017-03-15": ["Event 1", "Event 2"]
}

var output = Object.keys(input)
                   .map(function(key){
                       return { date: key, events: input[key]};
                   });
      
console.log(output);
```